# Commerce 2.0: How can multiple email addresses receive copies of orders?

Tags: commerce

If I understand the configuration correctly, only one email address can be specified when defining a Store (the text under the field says "Store email notifications are sent from this address".

When a person places an order, they will receive an email confirmation showing as being sent from that Store owner's email address. No one else - not even the store owner - gets an email copy of the order.

I am converting a client's website from Wordpress to Drupal 8. Their current configuration is that four different people in the office all receive email copies whenever an order is placed. How can the same be implemented in Commerce 2.0? (They don't want to log into the site and check the database for new orders - they want the email notifications sent to them if and when orders are actually placed.)

Has anyone already implemented something similar?

Answer (score 1):

> Their current configuration is that four different people in the office all receive email copies whenever an order is placed.

See our documentation for order receipt emails: https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/user-guide/orders/customer-emails

I think you'll be fine adding those four emails separated by commas.

EDIT: Also see our docs for setting up HTML emails https://docs.drupalcommerce.org/commerce2/developer-guide/core/html-emails

Comment: Matt:  Sorry for my delay in responding - I was busy taking the client's site live.  At the time I made my original post that section of the documentation you referred to was blank.  AndyD328 over on Drupal.org indicated on Oct 17 that he was going to add that section to the docs.

Comment: marrer let me know if my answer works, to send multiple emails by just entering `email1@example.com, email2@example.com` and so on. That way it can be found here and we can update the docs.